# Correct way of using Func<Task<T>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task, func

I have two code section in both of them I'm trying to use Func<Task>. Can anyone point out the difference between below two code sections. Which approach should I follow.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Task<int>> getter = async () => await Get();

    int x = getter().Result;

    Console.WriteLine("hello : " + x);
}
        
static async Task<int> Get()
{
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     return 1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Func<Task<int>> getter = () => Get();

     int x = getter().Result;

     Console.WriteLine("hello : " + x);
}
        
static async Task<int> Get()
{
      await Task.Delay(1000);
      return 1;
}
```

Comment: So you are asking about the difference between `async () => await Get()` and `() => Get()`, correct?

Comment: Nick Chapsas has a video on YT about this. I think that it is this one: https://youtu.be/aaC16Fv2zes

Answer (score 2):

The difference is a stacktrace in case of errors. If you modify the code a bit as following, you would see how results differ.

```
internal class Example1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Task<int>> getter = async () => await Get();

        int x = getter().Result;

        Console.WriteLine("hello : " + x);
    }

    static async Task<int> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("test");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1;
    }
}

internal class Example2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Task<int>> getter = () => Get();

        int x = getter().Result;

        Console.WriteLine("hello : " + x);
    }

    static async Task<int> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("test");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When Example1 throws the exception, you see a stacktrace as following. Looking at the stacktrace, you know that the Get() method was called from the anonymous method.

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    StackOverflow.CSharp.Example1.Get() in Example.cs
    StackOverflow.CSharp.Example1.Main.AnonymousMethod__0_0() in Example.cs
```

However, when Example2 throws the exception, the stacktrace is reduced and does not show where Get() was called from. It could be hard to trace a potential problem.

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    StackOverflow.CSharp.Example2.Get() in Example.cs
```

In our projects, we prefer the first approach with async/await.

Answer (score 0):

For a trivial case like this both examples will do more or less the same thing.

As a rule of thumb you should return the task directly without awaiting where you can. I.e. in cases where you call a single method that returns a task and do not do any processing of the result. But this is mostly for code style reasons, i.e. avoiding unnecessary keywords that might confuse a reader. So example 2 would be preferred.

Ofc. In your specific example you should probably not use async at all, and prefer `Thread.Sleep`. In a UI program you should avoid using `.Result`, since it will block the UI thread, and increases the risk of deadlocks.